# Rspec - "All examples were filtered out"

Tags: rspec

I'm currently studying QA using capybara/rspec on ruby. After a few classes using tag (include) i started getting the "All examples were filtered out message" one every examples, even the ones that were working before.

I already tried setting new configs on spec_helper such as:

```
  RSpec.configure do |c|

  c.filter_run :focus => true

  c.run_all_when_everything_filtered = true

  end
```

and

```
  RSpec.configure do |c|

  c.filter_run_when_matching :focus => true

  end
```

I also tried to remove the tags from the examples, but nothing seems to work.

I'm using rspec 3.9.0 version right now.

Can anyone give me some light on this matter?

Comment: Do you remember what you did before started having this issue? (like changing config/adding examples). Can you try to back-track those changes one by one?

Comment: The first example config looks good to me. How do you start your test run, whith which command?